# Getting a single random result using PDO MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello I would like the result to give me a single random charity's Paypal email address.  It works in MYSQL and I've tried in PDO to no avail.

Here's what I've been trying (not working PDO):

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM charities ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['paypal'];
```

I keep getting an array of email addresses not one single random one.

Here's what I had (working). I just want 1 random :

```
$dbh = mysql_connect(localhost, adsintha_main, 'verbum123*'); 
mysql_select_db('adsintha_city', $dbh);

$charities = mysql_query("select * from charities ORDER BY RAND() limit 1", $dbh); // list of charity donation email addresses
$row = mysql_fetch_array($charities);
$chosen_charity = $row['paypal'];
echo $chosen_charity;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: we're not a conversion service; read the manual and try something http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php *"Hello I want to convert this traditional MYSQL into PDO MYSQL"* - Ok, so do it. Or was that supposed to have read as *"Hello I want YOU to convert this traditional MYSQL into PDO MYSQL"*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code conversion.

Comment: Good luck with your PDO conversion. Do try and use prepared statements with placeholder values whenever possible since now's a good time to plug all those [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Seeing your query, you dont even have to use `prepare()`, simply connect to the database using `PDO` and use the `query()` method.

Comment: Hi Fred, I edited my question to show some of my attemps

Comment: What is `$row`? You need to use the at symbol to tag users. Fred won't get notifications without it. E.g. @Fred-ii- `$db` is a PDO connection, did it connect successfully, do you have error reporting on and are checking logs?

Comment: @chris85 I do get a successful connection using PDO.  $row: That was used in a solution I found on here.

Comment: @fred-ii Hi Fred, I edited my question to show some of my attempts

Comment: `var_dump($row);` what do you get?